# Regex script find and replace

Tags: regex, wcag2.0

I have tens of thousands of anchor links that need to be updated to conform to WCAG2.0. I did a find/replace in Notepad++ to add an aria-label="" attribute to each anchor link. Now I am trying to find the best way to populate the value of each aria-label with the respective link text.

I am assuming regex would be necessary due to the complexity of matching separate cases, but if you have another technique to recommend, I am eager to lean.

[Here is a link to sample code so you can understand what I am trying to accomplish](https://regexr.com/3rm1o), however I haven't been able to figure out how to target the text I am after.

What I am trying to do is copy the contents of the first column of each table (ie. January 2017) as well as the column preceding each pair of links (ie. Brew Pubs) and append that as a concatenated string to the start of each respective pair of aria-labels (Ie. January 2017 Brew Pub Excel)

Comment: You'll probably get a few comments about using an HTML parser instead of a regex for this.  Are you comfortable in other languages such as Python for example?

Comment: @sniperd I'll research using an HTML parser, thanks for the suggestion. As for other languages, I'm only familiar with Javascript, jQuery and a little PHP

Comment: You can use any of those to parse up your HTML.  Just google around for Javascript HTML parser, or what not.  It will by like magic.  If you are still stuck or _really_ just want to play with regexes, post back and I can try and help out.

Comment: @sniperd Sounds good, thanks for the guidance. I'm reading up now and will reach back out if I can't figure it out

Comment: If your links have proper link text, there is no need to use `aria-label`. The `aria-label` attribute values overwrite the link text, so if you insist on having it, the value should be the same as the link text. But this just creates unnecessary overhead for you.